# Group By within contain cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Hellow , I want to use group by within contain in cakephp. In the following case i want to take only distinct organization within organizationUser array..

```
         $options = array(
        'conditions' => array('User.' .$this->User->primaryKey => $userId), 
        'contain' => array(
                        'OrganizationUser'=>array(
                            'conditions'=>['status'=>3],
                            'group'=> array( 'OrganizationUser.organization_id')),
                        'OrganizationUser.Organization',
                        'OrganizationUser.Organization.Noticeboard',
                        'OrganizationUser.Organization.Newsboard',
                        'OrganizationUser.Organization.Noticeboard.Branch',
                    ),
        'page'=>$page,
        'limit'=>$limit
        );



        $org = $this->User->find('all', $options);
```

But this is throwing error like 'Column not found', and 'conditions' is working fine within OrganizationUser but 'group' not working.I am using cakephp version 2.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think cakephp 2+ offer something like you are doing to make field distinct within contain. So better to try following..
Replace :

```
'group'=> array( 'OrganizationUser.organization_id')
```

By

```
'fields'=> array( 'DISTINCT OrganizationUser.organization_id')
```

that might work for you.

Comment: Well, an alternative approach with better control would be to use `joins` with query builder... I'd post a new answer but since the issue was addressed in cake 3.0, I don't think it deserves anything more than a comment on this clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using cake version 4+.

In my table the relation I've made

```
$this->belongsTo('CreatedOperator')
      ->setClassName(USERS_PLUGIN . '.Users')
      ->setForeignKey('created_by')
      ->setJoinType('INNER')
   ;
```

and I'm calling the relation like

```
       $query
        ->disableHydration()
        ->select([
            'CreatedOperator.id',
            'CreatedOperator.first_name',
            'CreatedOperator.last_name',
            'full_name' => $query->func()->concat(['CreatedOperator.first_name' => 'identifier',' ','CreatedOperator.last_name' => 'identifier']),
            'total' => $query->func()->count('CreatedOperator.id')])
        ->contain(['CreatedOperator'])
        ->group(['CreatedOperator.id'])
        ;

    return $query->toList();
```